# Angular2 - Typescript drag and drop make an item dragged droppable

Tags: html, typescript, angular, drag-and-drop

I'm working with angular2 typescrit
I have a div with format A4 like page and I fill this div(page) by using some drag&drop to add divs to organize my page

and I need inside this Div to apply another drag&drop to add for example table or paragraph

so my problem is when I need to do the second drag&drop the divs are not considered as the real html code in my page however they are displayed in the view (navigator)

so I cant use my drag and drop

there is any solution to resolve this problem ??

thanks

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs span2 clearfix"></ul>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="sidebar-nav">
                    <ul class="nav nav-list accordion-group">
                        <li class="rows" id="estRows" [dragula]='"first-bag"'>
                            <div >
                                <div class="preview"><input type="text" value="12" placeholder="Enter your own" class="form-control"></div>
                                <div class="view">
                                    <div class="row" >
                                        <div class=" col-md-12 column"  dnd [drop]="true"> </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lyrow">
                                <span class="drag label label-default "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></i> drag</span>
                                <div class="preview"><input type="text" value="6 6" placeholder="Enter your own" class="form-control"></div>
                                <div class="view">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="container col-md-6 column" **[dragula]='"first-bag"'>**</div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 column"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lyrow">
                                <span class="drag label label-default "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></i> drag</span>
                                <div class="preview"><input type="text" value="8 4" placeholder="Enter your own" class="form-control"></div>
                                <div class="view">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-8 column"></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4 column"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lyrow">
                                <span class="drag label label-default "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></i> drag</span>
                                <div class="preview"><input type="text" value="4 4 4" placeholder="Enter your own" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="view">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4 column"></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4 column"></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4 column"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lyrow">
                                <span class="drag label label-default display-none"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></i> drag</span>
                                <div class="preview"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter your own" class="form-control"></div>
                                <div class="view">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav nav-list accordion-group" >
                        <li class="nav-header"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Base CSS
                            <div class="pull-right popover-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign "></i>
                                <div class="popover fade right">
                                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                                    <h3 class="popover-title">Help</h3>
                                    <div class="popover-content">Drag &amp; Drop the elements inside the columns where you want to insert
                                        it. And
                                        from there, you can configure the style of that element. If you need more info please visit <a
                                                target="_blank" href="http://getbootstrap.com/css">Base CSS.</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li dnd>
                            <div class="preview">Paragraph</div>
                            <div class="view" >
                                <p contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam
                                    eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu sem sapien,
                                    sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, pharetra in dolor. Sed iaculis posuere
                                    diam ut cursus. <em>Morbi commodo sodales nisi id sodales. Proin consectetur, nisi id commodo imperdiet,
                                        metus nunc consequat lectus, id bibendum diam velit et dui.</em> Proin massa magna, vulputate nec
                                    bibendum nec, posuere nec lacus.
                                    <small>Aliquam mi erat, aliquam vel luctus eu, pharetra quis elit. Nulla euismod ultrices massa, et
                                        feugiat ipsum consequat eu.
                                    </small>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">

        <form >
            <label for="nameTemp">Section Name :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  />
            <br/>
            <label for="content">Content:</label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Update Doc.</button>
            <br/><br/>


            <div class="container page" id="content" [dragula]='"first-bag"' size="A5" layout="portrait" contenteditable="true"
                >

            </div>
        </form></div>
```

and I created my own directive a simple directive to drag and drop (dnd)

Comment: What are you using for drag'n'drop? Add more details and code snippets

Comment: I'm using dragula
https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula

Comment: when I drag element under [dragula] = <li>
to div [dragula]='first-bag' it works

when I need to do another drag from my directive  dnd (or dragula) to the element wich I dropped 
is like he dont found the code html however they are displayed